# Pass user and group to a shell script on commandline

Tags: permissions, root, shell-scripting

I ahve a requirement to run a script thats only runnable with a specific user and group. The format of the command is like

```
$PROGRAM_HOME/bin/installService.sh [USER [GROUP]]
```

I tried running the script as

```
$PROGRAM_HOME/bin/installService.sh root root
```

But I get the following error

```
** ERROR: Only root user can install artifactory as a service
```

When I run it with sudo I get another eror

```
** ERROR: Could not change values in /etc/init.d/artifactory
```

Here is the exact error

```
** INFO: Please edit the files in /etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory to set the correct environment
Especially /etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory/default that defines ARTIFACTORY_HOME, JAVA_HOME and JAVA_OPTIONS
cp: /etc/init.d/artifactory: No such file or directory
chmod: /etc/init.d/artifactory: No such file or directory
sed: illegal option -- -
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]

** ERROR: Could not change values in /etc/init.d/artifactory


Whats the correct syntax to run it as a root?
```

Some of the steps I followed to debug

I am on version 4.11.1 which is the version I am specifically interested in

I am following the steps from the doc https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing+on+Linux+Solaris+or+Mac+OS

I am on a Mac OSX EI Capitan 10.11.5

After the error I did fix the ARTIFACTORY_HOME location in /opt/jfrog/artifactory/default

I ran the install script with sudo -s as root but get the same exact error.

I also tried another version to see if there was an issue with the script in this version but get the same error

My guess is that this portion of the script fails

```
installService() {
    serviceName=$(basename $artServiceFile)
    serviceFiles=$artBinDir/../misc/service
    if [ -e "$artServiceFile" ]; then
        cp -f $artServiceFile $serviceFiles/$serviceName.init.backup
    fi
    cp -f $serviceFiles/artifactory $artServiceFile
    chmod a+x $artServiceFile
```

And the output from running the script in debug mode

```
root# bash -x ./installService.sh
+ checkRoot
+ curUser=
+ '[' -x /usr/xpg4/bin/id ']'
++ id -nu
+ curUser=root
+ '[' root '!=' root ']'
+ '[' ./installService.sh = . ']'
+ '[' ./installService.sh = source ']'
+++ dirname ./installService.sh
++ cd .
++ pwd
+ artBinDir=/opt/artifactory-pro-4.11.1/bin
+++ dirname /opt/artifactory-pro-4.11.1/bin
++ cd /opt/artifactory-pro-4.11.1
++ pwd
+ artExtractDir=/opt/artifactory-pro-4.11.1
+ ARTIFACTORY_HOME=/opt/artifactory-pro-4.11.1
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ artEtcDir=/etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory
+ TOMCAT_HOME=/opt/artifactory-pro-4.11.1/tomcat
+ artLogDir=/opt/artifactory-pro-4.11.1/logs
+ artRunDir=/opt/artifactory-pro-4.11.1/run
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ artServiceFile=/etc/init.d/artifactory
+ artDefaultFile=/etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory/default
+ getArtUser ''
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ '[' -z '' ']'
+ ARTIFACTORY_USER=artifactory
+ getArtGroup ''
+ '[' -n '' ']'
+ echo

+ echo 'Installing artifactory as a Unix service that will run as user artifactory'
Installing artifactory as a Unix service that will run as user artifactory
+ echo 'Installing artifactory with home /opt/artifactory-pro-4.11.1'
Installing artifactory with home /opt/artifactory-pro-4.11.1
+ createArtUser
+ echo -n 'Creating user artifactory...'
Creating user artifactory...++ getent passwd artifactory
++ awk -F: '{print $1}'
./installService.sh: line 40: getent: command not found
+ artifactoryUsername=
+ '[' '' = artifactory ']'
+ echo -n creating...
creating...++ which bash
+ useradd -m -s /usr/local/bin/bash artifactory
./installService.sh: line 45: useradd: command not found
+ '[' '!' 127 ']'
+ echo ' DONE'
 DONE
+ createArtGroup
+ '[' '' == '' ']'
+ return 0
+ createArtEtc
+ echo

+ echo -n 'Checking configuration link and files in /etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory...'
Checking configuration link and files in /etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory...+ '[' -L /opt/artifactory-pro-4.11.1/etc ']'
+ echo -n 'already exists, no change...'
already exists, no change...+ echo -e ' DONE'
 DONE
+ createArtDefault
+ echo -n 'Creating environment file /etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory/default...'
Creating environment file /etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory/default...+ '[' -e /etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory/default ']'
+ echo -n 'already exists, no change...'
already exists, no change...+ echo -e ' DONE'
 DONE
+ echo -e '\033[33m** INFO: Please edit the files in /etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory to set the correct environment\033[0m'
** INFO: Please edit the files in /etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory to set the correct environment
+ echo -e '\033[33mEspecially /etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory/default that defines ARTIFACTORY_HOME, JAVA_HOME and JAVA_OPTIONS\033[0m'
Especially /etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory/default that defines ARTIFACTORY_HOME, JAVA_HOME and JAVA_OPTIONS
+ createArtRun
+ '[' '!' -d /opt/artifactory-pro-4.11.1/run ']'
+ installService
++ basename /etc/init.d/artifactory
+ serviceName=artifactory
+ serviceFiles=/opt/artifactory-pro-4.11.1/bin/../misc/service
+ '[' -e /etc/init.d/artifactory ']'
+ cp -f /opt/artifactory-pro-4.11.1/bin/../misc/service/artifactory /etc/init.d/artifactory
cp: /etc/init.d/artifactory: No such file or directory
+ chmod a+x /etc/init.d/artifactory
chmod: /etc/init.d/artifactory: No such file or directory
+ sed --in-place -e '
     /processname:/ s%artifactory%artifactory%g;
     /Provides:/ s%artifactory%artifactory%g;
     s%# pidfile: .*%# pidfile: /opt/artifactory-pro-4.11.1/run/artifactory.pid%g;
     s%/etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory/default%/etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory/default%g;
     ' /etc/init.d/artifactory
sed: illegal option -- -
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
+ errorArtHome 'Could not change values in /etc/init.d/artifactory'
+ echo

+ echo -e '\033[31m** ERROR: Could not change values in /etc/init.d/artifactory\033[0m'
** ERROR: Could not change values in /etc/init.d/artifactory
+ echo

+ exit 1
```

Comment: Try to run as root.

Comment: isnt sudo running it as root?

Comment: There is no sudo in your question.

Comment: When I run it with sudo it gives me the second error as mentioned in my question

Comment: Ohh, i see... Are you sure you need this software? Doesn't look too fault-tolerant.

Comment: Following this doc https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing+on+Linux+Solaris+or+Mac+OS, not sure how else to run as root if not sudo

Comment: Then install from `.deb` or `.rpm`. It must be easier.

Comment: thats not an option unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately sometimes these things happen. Maybe the script is old or written for a different OS or you have missing packages it requires or it just sucks. There are ways to deal with it.

You're asking about this from a shell scripting perspective, so that's how I'll answer. Besides, I don't know what your OS is (or version) and where you got that software (and it's version) and how you got to this point and exactly what you're trying to do.

**Have you followed the instructions** about defining settings in `/etc/opt/jfrog/artifactory` like it warns?

**Are you using the latest version** of this software/script?

**Your script is looking to modify/access (or create?) an init script** when it fails:

```
/etc/init.d/artifactory
```

**Debugging/fixing things**

Without knowing all the steps the script is taking, it's hard to tell why you are getting these messages.

First, gain a root shell, just for the heck of it. `sudo -s`, `sudo su -` or `su -` should get you there.

Then - does `/etc/init.d` exist? Does `/etc/init.d/artifactory` exist?

You can open up the script and read through it, looking for the problem. Or you can run it with step by step debugging output as:

```
bash -x <script> <args>
```

If fact, just running the script with `bash` can help sometimes as some shell scripts contain `#!/bin/sh` at the top, which can invoke `dash` instead on at least Ubuntu systems. Dash can cause some bash scripts to fail.

```
bash <script> <args>
```

When you find the problem (with the script or your system) fix it and rerun the script. Come back and update your question with helpful information if things don't work out.

Comment: Also, confirm you followed the directions from JFrog https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Installing+on+Linux+Solaris+or+Mac+OS#InstallingonLinuxSolarisorMacOS-ServiceInstallation.

Comment: Hi Ryan thanks for the detailed steps, I've updated the question

Comment: @user_mda I don't see anything new in the question.

Comment: Sorry please see now

Comment: @user_mda Try the debugging steps for bash (especially bash -x if you don't understand scripting languages too well). If you can't figure it out, you can add the section of output where the error is to your question.

Comment: @Ryan Thanks I've added more info, I can only figure out that the script fails at cpying that particular file. Still think its a permission ssue but confused as to why it would fail for a root user too

Comment: @user_mda I'd try to help more but I don't have OSX. I can see this will take time/work. What about following some instructions like this? http://tutorialforlinux.com/2014/07/07/how-to-getting-started-with-artifactory-java-repos-tool-on-mac-10-9-mavericks-os-x-easy-guide/ and skipping the whole init.d thing. Does OSX even support SysVinit scripts? Perhaps you can start it another way.

Comment: not very familiar with os level scripts, I assumed since the steps are described for a mac OS it should work out, but I'll spin up an ubuntu vm and see if I can install there

Comment: This works on Ubuntu!